# wcf routing service

Tags: .net, wcf

Question …. How can I expose the endpoint of my Wcf service, from router service to client…
my routing service only expose IRequestReplyRouter to my client.i want that my routing service shoud expose the endpoint of my service... 
router service web.config is as follows

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService" behaviorConfiguration="routing">
    <endpoint address=""  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="routing">
      <routing filterTableName="filtertables"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<routing >
  <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="filtertables"  >
      <add filterName="all" endpointName="WCF_QtrwiseSalesService" />
    </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
  <filters>
    <filter name="all" filterType="MatchAll"/>
  </filters>
</routing>
<client>
  <endpoint
                 name="WCF_QtrwiseSalesService" binding="netTcpBinding"
                  address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Design_Time_Addresses/BackUpList1/Service1/"
                  contract="*">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: You can´t, what are you trying to achive, or what is your actual error?

Comment: there is no error,my routing service only expose IRequestReplyRouter,well my requirement is i want to expose all endpoints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b31891be-98d3-4440-a617-f584435b01aa), it might help you, but from my experience using the WCF RoutingService I wouldn´t invest too much effort unless your requirements are a complete have-to-have